# Using NSPredicate to filter Array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, filter, nspredicate

What I want is my Array of swag, Apples, Oranges to be filtered by what it contains so if it contains a letter or a string of letters. I have this so far:

```
NSArray* test = @[@"swag", @"Apples", @"Oranges"];
//NSString *nameOnly = [[onlyApps lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]
NSString *searchinput = @"a";
NSPredicate * fltrSearch = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ contains[cd] '%@'", test,     searchinput];
NSArray * Search = [test filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltrSearch];
NSLog(@"%@", fltrSearch);
NSLog(@"%@", Search);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the below modified code:-

```
NSArray* test = @[@"swag", @"Apples", @"Oranges"];
NSString *searchinput = @"a";
NSPredicate * fltrSearch = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",searchinput];
NSArray * Search = [test filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltrSearch];
NSLog(@"%@", Search);
```

Your predicateWithFormat line is wrong. So just replace the below line:-

```
NSPredicate * fltrSearch = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ contains[cd] '%@'", test,     searchinput];
```

With Modified line:-

```
NSPredicate * fltrSearch = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",searchinput];
```

Output:-

```
(
    swag,
    Apples,
    Oranges
)
```

Comment: Ok what if I wanted to do this below?